# IE non-breaking space at the end of line

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, ckeditor

I've got an issue with internet Explorer > 10 and Firefox which is when you write **"foo "** and you let a white space at the end of line and you pass to view html source the white space is removed. if you let 2 white spaces at the end like **"foo  "** only one non-breaking space is shown on html source **"foo`&nbsp;`"**